# OpenELEC W/External 24/7 Ok to do?

Tags: hard-drive, openelec

So for a fathers day present my dad has been wanting a small media center forever, he saw my raspberry pi setup and loved it and wanted one for himself. So I got him a good setup, gonna throw openelec on it and Use an old external to store movies on.

Thing is, The whole "couch movie surfing" is difficult since Raspberry pi doesn't have an on switch. Also Im not sure how ok it is to leave on 24/7 with OpenELEC?

Is this going to cause issues with the external constantly being used or the raspberry pi constantly being on? They aren't super computer literate so it'd kinda be something I set up, and if they need more movies I just Put more on their external.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is not just "ok" to be run 24/7, it's actually designed to do so. I have a few units working non-stop and haven't seen any issues yet.

Regarding switches, the OpenELEC does automatically stop the video playback when TV is turned off or changed the channel, very convenient. The only thing you should think about is a good remote, because XMBC interface might get cumbersome from time to time.